# Record bash_history to private database for all users?

Tags: bash, database, history, sh

I want to be able to setup a MySQL database and record all commands issued on my server by username and command.  Is this possible, and if so, how would I set it up?

Comment: do you want this in real time or periodically updated - for example once a day? I would suggest regular review of users history file but it will left you with possibility of users removing specific entries from their history files. But there is a tool called script and it can log all commands to a txt file. You can add script command to users `.profile` file and restrict the editing of this file.

Answer (score 3):

You could

- play with `PROMPT_COMMAND` if you want this in *real-time* (each line),
  this could be something like:

  ```
  PROMPT_COMMAND='echo mysql -c "INSERT $(history 1|sed "s/^ *[0-9]* *//")"'
  ```

  this could be stored in your `$HOME/.bashrc`.
- play with `$HOME/.bash_logout` if you prefer *digest* at each `logout`.
  this could let you begin your own script, try adding something like this to your `.profile`

  ```
  if [ "$HISTFILE" ] ;then
      export OHISTFILE="$HISTFILE"
      export HISTFILE=$(mktemp $HOME/.bash_history_XXXXXXXX)
      touch $HISTFILE
      history -a
      cat >>"$OHISTFILE" "$HISTFILE"
      HISTFILE="$OHISTFILE"
      HISTFILESIZE=$HISTFILESIZE
      mysql -c "INSERT ... $(<$HISTFILE).."
      rm $HISTFILE
    fi
  ```

Comment: This is linked to [How to find out which ssh key was used](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/59943/27653).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **bash** or **zsh**, there is a project trying to accomplish this: [advanced-shell-history](http://code.google.com/p/advanced-shell-history/) .. Its abhorrent build system (*read the Makefile* before you go all `make install`) might be the reason why it hasn't been included in distributions - am working on it and will push upstream, then report back :)

If you want a history for the plain mysql cli shell, [rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/uck/rlwrap/) could be of use:

> This package provides a small utility that uses the GNU readline
>   library  to allow the editing of keyboard input for any other command.
>   Input  history is remembered across invocations, separately for each
>   command;  history completion and search work as in bash and completion
>   word lists  can be specified on the command line.